# Reading Win32 variables

Tags: c++, winapi

If I can hook into a Win32 process, will I be able to do:

- Read variables from inside a Class inside the process?
- I have a full source code for the Win32 app above, can I use that as reference for this subject?

Cheers.

Comment: If you can find where a variable is stored, and have the right permissions, go ahead: [ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx). That isn't to say this is something you'd particularly want to do in most cases.

Comment: -1, can you clarify what you're asking here?  I don't understand at all.

Comment: @MichaelKristofik He wants to write a program to attach to an already running program to read the contents of variables inside a class. He has source code for this running program. Basically he wants to implement a basic component of a debugger (variable watch/inspect).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean bu "hook into" the process?  Are you attaching to it like a debugger (and thus actually running in a separate process)?  Are you injecting code into the process (and thus running in that process's address space)?  Are you writing a HookProc?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Not like a debugger, more specifically a Process loading a DLL. Sorry for the vague term though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. As soon as your module is hooked into the process, you share the same address space. That means memory that the process has allocated (e.g. for class instances) will be accessible to you.

If you know the offset of the class instance, then you can either:

- cast this memory address to a pointer to the class (provided you have the class header included)
- use offsets from this memory address to access the class's members.

See [Traversing the Module List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686849%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN. Once you have the [MODULEENTRY32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684225%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the process you wish to "hook", you can use the `modBaseAddr` as a base for your offsets. For example if you know that a global variable which points to a class instance is at 0x000AD421, you can do:

```
ClassName *pClassBase = moduleEntry->modBaseAddr + 0x000AD421;
pClassBase->UseSomeFunctions();
```

or

```
unsigned char *pClassBase = moduleEntry->modBaseAddr + 0x000AD421; // if we don't know the exact definition of the class we want to play with
float flMemberValue = *reinterpret_cast<float*>((unsigned char *)pClassBase + 24); // float member value at offset 24
// value of member is flMemberValue

*reinterpret_cast<float*>((unsigned char *)pClassBase + 24) = 15.25; // setting the same member value to 15.25.
```

As stated by other commenters, finding the offset of the class base is the hardest part of this process. However if you have the class definitions handy, this is essentially the only piece of work you have to do (i.e. you don't also have to find the class member offsets, too).

Comment: The major issue is finding the addresses of stuff.  A non-debug build will have most of the metadata stripped out, making it rather complicated to find anything that isn't global (and even a bunch of stuff that is, in some cases).

Comment: Very much so. It's usually easier to inspect the equivalent Linux binary (the compiled assembly is similar my experience), and then use signature scanning at run-time to find the offsets. The fact that the question asker already knows how to hook into the process led me to believe that he already has the offsets. If not, then that's a completely different question.

Comment: @SaulRennison You mean if a host process loads a DLL, you mean the DLL can access a Class member variable in the host process? Also if I have the exe file, I can inspect that and do signature scanning at run-time, that is when the DLL is actually loaded? Furthermore, you mean the dll can signature-scan its host process?

Comment: @SaulRennison I was able to code the DLL in such a way that it can get its parent process ID

Comment: @SaulRennison your idea is the best one yet, I can accept this answer although I still have to know whether how to get the offset of the member variable; since I just asked about if my idea is possible.

Comment: I've updated my answer comment again if you need more information

Comment: @SaulRennison based on the answer from here, there's no way to get the Class offset as you proposed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149134/getting-class-offset-in-a-win32-binary

Comment: You don't get the offset of the class, you get the offset to a *pointer to the instance you want to alter*. For example, if I had: `CMyClass *g_pMyClassPointer;` as a global in my project, this pointer value is held in memory, at an offset which is static to the base (e.g. always at 0x000642AB). That way I can always access this global instance of CMyClass, and modify it as I wish. It is not possible to get an offset to a class, because classes don't really exist in the compiled code (other than as functions)