# Getting class offset in a Win32 binary

Tags: c++, winapi

For a Win32 Portable Executable (PE)

- How can I get the list of classes used
- How to get the offset of a given class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class does not have an offset - its methods have offsets. If the PE file is a DLL, and a class is exported, you can get offsets of its methods from the exported function table. The names will be mangled though. The mangling scheme is compiler- and version-specific.

You can use the DUMPBIN tool (available with Visual Studio, or in Platform SDK) to watch the export table. IIRC, it can even unmangle the names for you. If you want to do it programmatically, use the functions from the ImageHlp API - `ImageLoad()` and so forth.

There's no good way to get offsets of nonexported class methods.

Also, offsets can be found in a MAP file, or in debug symbols, or in a PDB file. If it's a third party product, those won't be available to you, most likely.

EDIT re: Microsoft DLLs. Microsoft makes debug symbols for a lot of their files (both Win32 and .NET) available via the Microsoft Symbol Server. Visual Studio since v. 2005 can pull those symbols automatically upon DLL loading.

Comment: When you say there's no good way, then there's a way but its not easy right? I have done getting exported functions of exe and dll.

Comment: There's no bad way either :) Unless explicitly preserved (e. g. in debug symbols or MAP file), C++ class names are lost after compilation and linking. Even if you disassemble the file, you'll be able to see where do functions begin and end, but you'll never know what was the compile-time name of that function. C++ is not a reflected language.

Comment: BTW, I got the idea with getting the class offset is from an answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126547/reading-win32-variables , from what you say it means the suggested solution from this is wrong?

Comment: The solution over there is predicated upon you knowing the addresses of sensible variables. That's not generally possible. While doing real life reverse engineering, you usually maintain a set of address/purpose guesses - "OK, the 4 bytes at address 0xa0006667 are initialized to output of CreateWindow(), so it must be a HWND, let's call it hwnd_1" and so forth. Some disassemblers, like IDA Pro, even maintain that mapping for you in a separate file.